# Packaging Android wear app in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, wear-os

How can I `turn off asset compression in eclipse`? I am have exported an Android Wear app packaged in Phone's app, however the wear app doesn't install on the smart watch, which means the phone wasn't able to recognize the wearable apk. I have followed this method to package Wear app in phone's app.

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's not needed, just put your wearable apk in the /raw folder (I already published a wearable app created using Eclipse on the Play Store and everything went fine).

Comment: Do you know any way to connect Android phone Emulator with Android Wear Emulator?

Comment: no, I use real hardware so I have no idea. But you may have a look at adb, I think it could connect both.